# How to fade in select options using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way I can fade in select options when the select is clicked and override the standard behavior?

Say I have the following select:

```
    <select id="size" class="" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="King Size (176cm)" class="attached enabled">King Size (176cm)</option>
    </select>
```

Is there a way I can make the options appear slowly with a fade in using jQuery?

Before anyone recommends it is not possible for me to change my select to a UL tag or any other html tag.

Comment: Select menus are styled and displayed by the browser in use. Unless you pull some CSS shenanigans with UL and LI items.. you can not style select options.

Comment: Create your own select box UI.

Comment: There is a great plugin with well described: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/Animated-Custom-Select-Box-with-jQuery-CSS3.html

Comment: @Luke That converts the select into `ul li` elements which is not what I want.

Comment: @user3574492 it doesn't matter. As Ivan wrote you, you cannot modify select's behavior. You have to make an own pseudo-select what basically this plugin does.

Comment: @Luke Okay, so basically you cannot do what I asked for, I clearly mentioned in my question that I cannot convert my select to different tags so there was no point in giving your solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the basic answer is you can't do such a thing as it's the browser which renders the select element. Of course there are alternative methods for getting around it such as using `ul` and `li` elements instead but that is not possible in my case as I have select dropdowns across my application and it's just not feasible to change them all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok hope this is what you are looking for :

I did this part only :

> fade in select options when the select is clicked

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#size").change(function(){
        $("#size").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="size" class="" name="attribute_size" data-attribute_name="attribute_size">
    <option value="">Choose an option</option>
    <option value="King Size (176cm)" class="attached enabled">King Size (176cm)</option>
  </select>
```

Hope that it help you .

Comment: There is nothing on the fiddle

Comment: @IvanRodriguezTorres is it showing now ? had to save , forgot that .

Comment: This fades out everything once I click an option, I want the select options to fade in when I click the select element as I said in my question.

Comment: @user3574492 oh , you mean when you click on the select it will pop up in a nice style ?

Comment: @Laith Not pop up, as in the dropdown options will expand down in a nice way.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('option').hide();
    $('#size').click(function (){
        $('option').fadeIn(900);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't

Explanation
You can't modify the select behaviour in that way, but you can use a bit of js to make some DOM elements have the same behavior. Here you have an example:

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".option").click(function() {
    $(".option").slideDown();
  });

  $(".option:not(.selected)").click(function() {
    $(".option:not(.selected)").slideUp();

    $(".option.selected").text($(this).text())
    $("#selectVal").val($(this).data("value"))
  });




});
```

```css
li {
  list-style: none
}

.option {
  display: none
}

.option:first-child {
  display: block
}

.option:not(.selected):hover {
  background: red
}

#select {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="select">
  <li class="option selected">--</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="">--</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="1">one</li>
  <li class="option" data-value="2">two</li>
</ul>
<input id="selectVal" type="hidden" value="" />
```

That is a basic code and can be optimized a lot, but it's a good starting point.

Another option is using a plugin, like [chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)